# How to calculate $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{g(x)}$, knowing $\lim_{x \to \infty}g(x)=-\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, continuity

I know a theorem using for calculate the limit of composite function.

> If $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=b$ and $\newcommand{\limto}[2]{\lim\limits_{{#1}\to{#2}}}\limto xa g(x)=b$ then, $$\limto xa f(g(x))= f \left( \limto xa g(x)\right) = f(b).$$

But if we need to calculate $ \limto x \infty e^{g(x)}$ knowing the  $\limto x \infty g(x)=-\infty$, I can not say $e^{x}$ is continuous at $-\infty$? I used to take it for granted that the limit is 0 but can not give proof of it.

Comment: This is a good observation, but I’m almost positive that a version of this theorem can be proven for infinite limits, similar to how l’Hopital’s rule has many “variants” depending on the case

Comment: Take $f(x)=\ln (1/x)=-\ln x$ to see what limit you should expect.

Comment: $e^{-\infty}=0$, not $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your known theorem includes the case $a=\infty$, your only problem is to generalize it to $b=-\infty$. You are right that it makes no sense to claim that $\exp:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is continuous at $-\infty$, but you can define $f:\overline{\Bbb R}\to\overline{\Bbb R}$ by
$$\begin{cases}f(x)=e^x&\text{if }x\in\Bbb R\\f(-\infty)=0&\\f(+\infty)=+\infty.&\end{cases}$$ This function is continuous when the [extended real line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) $\overline{\Bbb R}$ is equipped with its usual topology, so that your theorem applies:
$$\text{if }\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=-\infty\text{ then }\lim_{x\to a}f(g(x))=f(-\infty)=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Definitions will be enough. Note that $ e $ plays no role here and we can take any real number $ a > 1 $ instead.

$\lim \limits_{x\rightarrow +\infty} f(x) = - \infty $ means that $\forall M<0, \exists \delta : x \in (\delta, +\infty) \Rightarrow f(x)<M$ .Which gives us that $ 0<e^{f(x)} <e^M $. but you can make $|M|$ as big as you wish and so you can move $e^M$ as close to $0$ as you wish. Which gives us that (again, you can write that down with definition of limit) $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow +\infty} e^{f(x)}=0$

What about the fact that you think this limit is equal to one. You're probably confusing this with the case when the function tends to zero.
(for example
$a^{\frac{1}{x}} \rightarrow 1$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$ )

Answer (score 0):

You can use the epsilon-delta defintion of continuous of $f(x)$. Since $lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=-\infty$. There exists an $M>0$ as big as you want and an $x_0$ so that $f(x)<-M$ for all $x>x_0$. Then $e^{f(x)}<e^{-M}$ for all $x>x_0$ as M is arbitrary you can conclude by the triangle inquality.